Button with Command in WPF Popup always disabled
I created a custom button that can display a popup content on hover. The content to be displayed is sent via a property.
Setup
//Creating the popup if there's a content to be displayed:
_popup = new Popup
{
    PlacementTarget = this,
    Placement = PlacementMode.Top,
    VerticalOffset = -5,
    StaysOpen = false,
    Child = PopupContent,
    AllowsTransparency = true,
    PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Fade,
};

_popup.SetBinding(DataContextProperty, new Binding
{
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext")
});

//Later, on hover:
_popup.IsOpen = true;

I can use bindings pointing to the viewModel in use by the Window without any issues, except that Commands are not resolved (Buttons stay disabled).
Abridged example of a simple volume flyout/popup:
<c:ExButton Command="{Binding ToggleMuteCommand}" Content="Volume">
  <c:ExButton.PopupContent>
      <Border>
          <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="34"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <c:ExButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Mute" Command="{Binding ToggleMuteCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=EditorWindow}"/>

              <Slider Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding Volume, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="100"/>

              <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Volume, StringFormat=0}"/>
          </Grid>
      </Border>
  </c:ExButton.PopupContent>
</c:ExButton>

The command is created in the ViewModel and then assigned to the Window.CommandBindings:
new CommandBinding(_viewModel.ToggleMuteCommand, ToggleMute_Executed, _viewModel.HasProjectSoCanExecute),

Example
As you can see in the gif, the button inside the popup is always disabled.
The bindings are working, I checked by inspecting and via code behind. Both the button, the slider and the textblock have their bindings working.

What did I try so far?

Setting the DataContext (the ViewModel used by the window) to the Popup resulted in the Command not being null.
Setting the CommandBindings from the Window (or creating a new for the Popup) had no difference.
Removing the CanExecute callback, with no difference.
Setting the CommandTarget to the Window, to the Button or to the ViewModel also resulted in no differences.

Question

Why does the binding to the command result in null when the DataContext is null, but the other bindings still work normally?
What could be the cause of the command inside the popup not enablind the Button?


Are you sure that other bindings work normally when DataContext is null? They shouldn't. About main problem: routed event send from the popup won't reach CommandBinding at window level because the window is not a parent for the popup. Use Live Visual Tree tool window in Visual Studio to inspect element hierarchy.

Yes, it works, I'll show a gif of the popup.
I think it's an issue of the popup not being on the visual/logical tree as if I create a popup in XAML (the normal way), commands inside work normally.

Yeah, if I replace the logic with creating the popup in XAML and then just passing the reference to the button it works normally.
